# Internal/External Domain same name, having issues resolving webpage when typing https

Tags: ssl, iis, dns, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

So I inherited a domain for a client that has the same internal/external domain name (Server 2012r2). This caused a problem for users inside the domain trying to reach the external site.

After some research I decided to create an IIS redirect to the external website/IP, to enable people inside the domain to reach the external website.  This worked just fine.

Basically did what is at this link: http://oddjobsintech.com/active-directory-tip-access-external-website-with-the-same-domain-name-as-your-internal-domain/

Basically, just created a www A record and installed IIS on domain controllers with HTTP redirect to the external site.

However, now they've acquired an SSL cert from GoDaddy, and I installed on the external webserver, which works perfectly fine outside of the domain.  But once again, internally if you try to type "https:" the same issue with the page not resolving properly shows up.

Anybody know why this is and/or a possible fix (other than renaming the domain)?

Answer (score 0):

An Domain Controller is the hearth from every Microsoft Active Directory environment and Microsoft did a lot to prevent the access to it like written [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957044(v=ws.10).aspx):

> Domain controllers, by default, restrict the types of user accounts
>   that have the ability to log on locally. By default, only members of
>   the Account Operators, Administrators, Backup Operators, Print
>   Operators, and Server Operators groups have the Allowed logon locally
>   system right.

So you shouldn´t install an IIS on an domain controller. If the IIS will he hacked, the hacker has direct access to the whole domain!

According to your issue I would check the DNS environment if it is configured correctly.